# The right way to pass a list of list to a function, with missing and/or irrelevant elements

Tags: r, list

What is a robust way of passing a list of list of arguments to a function, when not all arguments are used by the function?

Parameters are stored in a named list of named lists

```
params <- list("1" = list(a = 1, b = 2),
               "2" = list(a = 3, b = 4, c = 5),  # not all parameters will be used
               "3" = list(a = 6, b = 7),
               "4" = list(a = 8))  # some parameters will be missing
```

The function uses some of these parameters, but not necessarily all of them (list "2"). Also it has default values, so I'd like it to work even if only some of its values are passed (list "4").

```
f <- function(a = 0, b = 0) 
    print(paste0("a = ", a, ", b = ", b))
```

I don't know how to pass an excessively populated list:

```
do.call(f, params[["2"]])
## Error in (function (a = 0, b = 0)  : unused argument (c = 5)
```

I would like to select and pass several lists at once. The expected output is something like what this loop produces:

```
selected <- c("1", "3")
for (i in selected)
  do.call(f, params[[i]])
## [1] "a = 1, b = 2"
## [1] "a = 6, b = 7"
```

Comment: If your answer involves ``lapply, "[",...``, please be patient with me. ;-)

Comment: I don't have any problem when running `do.call(f, params[["4"]])`? What is the version of your R? Or you clear all variables in your global environment and retry it.

Comment: @RonakShah, @ThomasIsCoding, you're right, ``do.call(f, params[["4"]])`` does work. Thanks! I must have had something in my environment. I'm editing the question to clarify. However, ``do.call(f, params[["2"]])`` still returns the error above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can allow optional arguments to your function

```
f <- function(a = 0, b = 0, ...) print(paste0("a = ", a, ", b = ", b))

for (i in seq_along(params)) {
  do.call(f, params[[i]])
}

#[1] "a = 1, b = 2"
#[1] "a = 3, b = 4"
#[1] "a = 6, b = 7"
#[1] "a = 8, b = 0"
```

Comment: Yes, I can allow optional arguments. Good point. You're okay with the use of a loop?

Comment: We don't have a real example here but I don't see any problem using the loop.